# Python multiprocessing fails when I try to run functions in other files

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I try to process some data in parallel using the *multiprocessing* module. Everything works fine when I had all the code in one file. I decided to split the code in seperate files (all in the same directory) but the multiprocessing doesn't work anymore. Can you please help me?

This is a minimal **working** example. All the code is in the same file.

**foo.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def process_data( q, msg1, msg2 ):
    q.put( [ msg1, msg2 ] )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = Queue()
    p = Process( target=bar.run, args=( q, "Hello", "World" ) )
    p.start()

    result = q.get()
    print( result )
    p.join()
```

Here is the **non working** example. The process_data function is now in another file (bar.py) and it seems that `result = q.get()` will never return! Both files are in the same directory:

**bar.py:**

```
def process_data( msg1, msg2 ):
    q.put( [msg1, msg2 ] )
```

**foo.py:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import bar

if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = Queue()
    p = Process( target=bar.process_data, args=( q, "Hello", "World" ) )
    p.start()

    result = q.get()
    print( result )
    p.join()
```

Comment: In bar.py  process_data function is missing the q parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your `process_data` function described in `bar.py` has only 2 arguments `(msg1, msg2)`, but it must have 3 arguments `(q, msg1, msg2)` because when you create a process, you pass these 3 arguments to it:

`p = Process( target=bar.process_data, args=( q, "Hello", "World" ) )`

Just change the `process_data` function definition in `bar.py` to:

`def process_data( q, msg1, msg2 ):
    q.put( [msg1, msg2 ] )`